# MPI Array undeclared

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, hpc

I am attaching a Minimal Reproducing Example of the error that I am facing in a large code. Say I have 2 processes, P0 and P1. I am declaring an array `int arr[2]` inside P0 and storing a value in `arr[0]`. Then I am redeclaring `int arr[2]` for P1 only, but whenever I am trying to access it inside P1, I am getting `‘arr’ undeclared (first use in this function) 37 |  arr[1]=1;` error. I am attaching the code here.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{

     MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
     int myrank, size; //size will take care of number of processes  
     double sTime, eTime, time,max_time;
     
     MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank) ;
     MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    
     int r=0, c;  
      
     if(myrank==0)
     {
        int arr[2];
        arr[0]=1;
     }

     if(myrank!=0)
     {
        int arr[2]; 
     }

     if(myrank==1)
     {
       arr[1]=2;
       MPI_Send(&arr[1], 1 , MPI_INT, 0 /*dest*/ , 100 /*tag*/ , MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    
     }

     MPI_Status status[2];

     if(myrank==0)
     {
        MPI_Recv(&arr[1],1 , MPI_INT, 1 /*src*/ , 100 /*tag*/, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status[1]);
    
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
           printf(" %d",arr[i]);
        }
   }
   MPI_Finalize();
   return 0;
}
```

To prevent this error I have tried declaring `int arr[2]` inside

```
if(myrank==1){
    int arr[2];
    arr[1]=2;
    
    MPI_Send(arr[1], 1 , MPI_INT, 0 /*dest*/ , 100 /*tag*/ , MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
```

But this time I get this error,

‘arr’ undeclared (first use in this function)
47 |  MPI_Recv(arr[0],1 , MPI_INT, 1 /*src*/ , 100 /*tag*/, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status[1]);

I am not able to get what is wrong here. Any suggestions will be really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error is because you declared a variable inside a if statement and you want to used outside that if. In C that is not possible, when you do:

```
if(myrank==0)
{
    int arr[2];
    arr[0]=1;
}
```

the array `int arr[2];` will only exist in the scope of that if statement. Therefore, if you try to access it outside it leads to a compilation error.

To get around you can either declare `int arr[2]` outside the `if` statement (but then all MPI process would allocated), or declare a pointer to `int` outside and only allocate memory for that pointer for the process that you want, namely:

```
int *arr = NULL;
if(myrank==0)
{
    arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
    arr[0]=1;
}
```

when the array is not longer needed do not forget to free it:

```
free(arr);
```

Another option (that works in your example) is to rearrange the code so that you have all the code related with the one process in one `if` branch, and the code from the other process in another `if` branch, namely:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
     MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);   
     int myrank, size; //size will take care of number of processes 
     double sTime, eTime, time,max_time;
     MPI_Status status[2];
     MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank) ;
     MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
   
    int r=0, c;  
      
    if(myrank==0)
    {
       int arr[2];
       arr[0]=1;
       MPI_Recv(&arr[1],1 , MPI_INT, 1 /*src*/ , 100 /*tag*/, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status[1]);
    
       for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
         printf(" %d",arr[i]);
    }
    if(myrank==1)
    {
       int arr[2];    
       arr[1]=2;
       MPI_Send(&arr[1], 1 , MPI_INT, 0 /*dest*/ , 100 /*tag*/ , MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```